# Impulses in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an app where I am applying an impuluse to a physics body.

It works perfectly fine in the simulator, where as when the app is installed on the device, it doesn't work fine, meaning the impulse is not applied properly.

What could be reason for this behavior? I tried to delete the app from the simulator and install it again. It works perfectly fine in the simulator.

Please advise. Thanks.

```
    ball1.size = CGSizeMake(siz/2,siz/2)
    ball1.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,self.frame.size.height/2 + (sizy*4))
    ball1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: siz/4)
    ball1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(ballmask)
    ball1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(bodymask) | UInt32(brickmask) | UInt32(barmask) | UInt32(bordermask)
    ball1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = UInt32(bodymask) | UInt32(brickmask) | UInt32(barmask) | UInt32(bordermask)
    ball1.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    ball1.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    ball1.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    ball1.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    ball1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
```

Comment: *"not applied properly"* - in what way? Please be as specific as possible, include the important code or even a short gif of what is going on.

Comment: @luk2302 In the simulator, the object moves continuously in the world. In the phone (physical device), the object moves very slowly towards the edge of the world and stops there. Linear Damping = 0, Restitution =1 , Friction = 0 of the object.

Comment: where do you assign any velocity or apply force to get it moving at all?

Comment: ball1.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(120, -120))

Comment: Sound like the behavior on the physical device is correct - strange... I sadly cannot help you without getting my hand on a complete project. If you really cannot figure it out, try removing **as much** code as possible from the project and upload it somewhere for me / us to check out. Try to create a MCVE - you might even stumble upon the problem / solution on your own while trying to do that.